# Is there a private API in iOS that I can use to read/write save data from another app?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

My sons iPod is suffering from this issue http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1368

Basically the only thing I can to to fix this is to reset the iPod without restoring a backup. He wants to fix his iPod but he does not want to lose his saved games (at least PvZ). I have an iOS developer account so if I could write a small app to save off this data and later write it back he would be golden.

What I am looking for is a way to write a simple app like http://www.imore.com/app-data-appbackup-jailbreak but I do not want to jailbreak his phone I just want to use the private api to accomplish the same thing and just load it using the dev account.

> This is a valid question I simply what to know if these API's exist. I do not plan to us this except for personal devices. If you down-vote please explain why.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue listed above with this post https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4309531?start=0&tstart=0 It would still be nice to know of an API that would help retrieve saved game info.

Comment: Jailbreaking isn't permanent.  You can jailbreak the phone just to install openssh, login and copy the data you want, and then do an iTunes restore when you're done to undo the jailbreak.  Just another option.  P.S.  If you ask anything about jailbreak development (or something like this), you'll often encounter lots of anti-open-development reaction from people who assume you're a malicious hacker, or pirate.  Unfortunate, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to write new code - other people have had this problem.

Several 3rd-party apps (that I haven't personally tried) purport to be able to get other apps' data:

- http://addpod.com/juicephone
- http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/features/mount-iphone-disk-mode-file-folder-access/
- http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

Note that there are some limitations - if the data is encrypted you'll have to retrieve the key *somehow*. Probably that requires a jailbreak or some more serious hacking.